# Using custom fonts in Xcode 6 - Swift

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift! I'd like to know how I can use custom fonts in my swift application in Xcode 6.

Comment: Woah, okay- but seriously, I'm new. I didn't know- someone removed the Xcode tag. There's no reason to down-vote it.

Comment: The "swift" in the title and tag are redundant but the "xcode 6" is useful because with xcode 6 there is no need to mess around with the plist anymore, making previous answers obsolete.

Comment: the linked thread is cluttered, has a lots of outdated information and does not contain swift as a language. Meaning: not a real answer. How old an cluttered has an answer to become to not be a duplicate?

Comment: Please reopen this question. The supposed duplicate is a mess of outdated answers and objective c. It is very difficult to find a good Swift answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You just drag the font file (.ttf) into the resources area on the left pane of Xcode.

When you drop it in, a dialog box will appear. Make sure the target for your application checkbox is checked. Then add the following key to your plist:

> Fonts provided by application

With the values of the filename "myFont.ttf"

---

**UPDATE** (see comment below)

Also make sure the font is added to the Copy Bundle Resources (found under Target -> Build Phases) I just spent about an hour on this, and I was the one who answered this question months ago lol.

---

**UPDATE**

Another helpful tip to find the name of the font for the font-family if you are using CSS is to run the following command:

```
NSLog("Available fonts: %@", UIFont.familyNames());
```

It prints out all the font name available to the system, including the ones you custom added.

Comment: I was able to access the font from the interface builder, but fail when using it in code. Turn out that the fonts must be added to targets->Build Phase ->Copy Bundle Resources too (http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)