# Using custom font in SpriteKit for OSX in swift

Tags: macos, swift, fonts, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

So I'm trying to use a custom font "Impact". It works fine if the font is installed on the computer, but if it's not I can't seem to get it to work. I bring in the .ttf file to the project, add it to the info.plist like this:

```
Impact.ttf
```

And I've tried multiple methods for using that font on a SKLabel but nothing works. Here's what I've tried:

```
let restartLabel: SKLabelNode =  SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Impact-Regular")
let restartLabel: SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Impact")
let restartLabel: SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Impact.ttf")
```

Any ideas? I would really appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using custom fonts in Xcode 6 - Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290400/using-custom-fonts-in-xcode-6-swift)

Comment: @sangony sadly nothing from that works. I've got the font in copy bundle resources, it's part of the target, everything. I've done this before but on iOS but not OSX, I guess I can check and see if it works on iOS.

Comment: Ok, I just tested the same exact code and process on iOS and it worked. So it must be some issue with spriteKit on Mac or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is here [Custom font in a Cocoa application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283572/custom-font-in-a-cocoa-application)

It turns out that the app didn't know where to look for the font, but setting the Application fonts resource path in info.plist made it work. I actually left the value blank since the font in just in MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the e[xact same name of your font](http://www.911fonts.com/font/download_ImpactRegular_5200.htm). So if you want to use the Impact Regular font, you need to call it like that:

```
SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Impact Regular")
```

Without the `-`.